# 10 Second Delay Before Curl POST due to ipv6 (Ubuntu)

Tags: json, post, curl, ipv6, ipv4

**NOTE: I don't want to delete any of the history below, but where I thought this was a Heroku issue before, it is not. I think it is an issue with my local machine sending posts via curl and ruby Net::HTTP**

I'm currently beginning to work on a rails app on Heroku (free) and in order to get some test data into the app I have a rake task that takes the test data from my DEV DB and posts to a JSON REST API on the heroku app like so:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://SITENAME.herokuapp.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/users.json")
request.add_field('Content-Type', 'application/json')
request.body = {'user' => User.first.to_hash }.to_json
response = http.request(request)
```

For some reason, every request takes almost exactly 10 seconds.  I then changed the top line to:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000")
```

...and the requests process incredibly fast.  Does anybody know if Heroku is slowing down POSTS on the free version?  (it would make sense since they want you to pay for the worker dyno) I'm eventually going to pony up for the paid version, but want to get a little further in my DEV before doing so.  Also, if they're not intentionally slowing them down, I'm a little hesitant to use them until I know why the posts are taking so long.  The line that is taking 10 seconds is:

```
response = http.request(request)
```

I'm sure that was obvious, but I figured I'd mention it.

**UPDATE 3/12**
Just wanted to post some of my logs from today.  All of the requests are taking 10 seconds:

```
1400
Before: 2013-03-12 21:30:33 UTC
After: 2013-03-12 21:30:43 UTC
1401
Before: 2013-03-12 21:30:43 UTC
After: 2013-03-12 21:30:54 UTC
1402
Before: 2013-03-12 21:30:54 UTC
After: 2013-03-12 21:31:04 UTC
1403
Before: 2013-03-12 21:31:04 UTC
After: 2013-03-12 21:31:14 UTC
1404
Before: 2013-03-12 21:31:14 UTC
After: 2013-03-12 21:31:24 UTC
1405
Before: 2013-03-12 21:31:24 UTC
After: 2013-03-12 21:31:34 UTC
```

**UPDATE 3/15**
To make sure it wasn't just the Net::HTTP::Post library causing the block I made the same request as above with curl and it also took 10 seconds:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d {"params":{"q":"query"} http://SITENAME.herokuapp.com/users.json
```

Anybody have a heroku trick I can use (other than new_relic) to tell where the delay is happening?

**UPDATE 3/15 #2**
Just switched to unicorn on my Heroku app and still getting the 10 second delay with both Ruby Net::HTTP::Post and using curl from the shell.  Switching to localhost, the post comes back immediately.

**UPDATE 3/28**

Per recent comment, posting the heroku logs with extremely fast response times:

```
2013-03-29T03:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/user.json" for IP
2013-03-29T03:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"user"=>{data}}
2013-03-29T03:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UserController#create as JSON
2013-03-29T03:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (2.2ms)  <<<SQL>>>
2013-03-29T03:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
2013-03-29T03:22:06+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users.json host=HOST.herokuapp.com fwd="66.31.201.99" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=33ms status=200 bytes=16
2013-03-29T03:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users.json" for 66.31.201.99 at 2013-03-29 03:22:16 +0000
2013-03-29T03:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UserController#create as JSON
2013-03-29T03:22:16+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users.json host=HOST.herokuapp.com fwd="66.31.201.99" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=16
2013-03-29T03:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: Parameters: {"user"=>{data}}
2013-03-29T03:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (2.0ms)  SQL
2013-03-29T03:22:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

**UPDATE 3/28 #2**

Just tried the curl from an online shell: www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php and it returned immediately, so I guess it's something with my machine.  Anybody know how I can troubleshoot where a curl is getting caught.  The format of the request that is 10 seconds locally but instantaneous in the online shell is:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"user":"payload"}' http://APP.herokuapp.com/users.json
```

**UPDATE 3/28 #3**

Something on my machine is causing the delay.  I ran the following to get the current system time and then perform the curl in verbose mode and the 10 second delay happens before the curl is even sent:

```
date +"%T" && curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"user":"payload"}' http://APP.herokuapp.com/users.json -v --trace-time -S
```

...and the output...

```
00:44:16  [start time from date +"%T"]
00:44:26.653510 * About to connect() to APP.herokuapp.com port 80 (#0)
00:44:26.653632 *   Trying 184.72.248.52... connected
00:44:26.675676 > POST /users.json HTTP/1.1
00:44:26.675676 > User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
00:44:26.675676 > Host: APP.herokuapp.com
00:44:26.675676 > Accept: */*
00:44:26.675676 > Content-type: application/json
00:44:26.675676 > Content-Length: 653
00:44:26.675676 > 
00:44:26.675954 * upload completely sent off: 653out of 653 bytes
00:44:26.717286 < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
00:44:26.717380 < Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
00:44:26.717518 < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
00:44:26.717552 < Date: Fri, 29 Mar 2013 04:44:33 GMT
00:44:26.717584 < Etag: "7363e85fe9edee6f053a4b319588c086"
00:44:26.717616 < Status: 200 OK
00:44:26.717647 < X-Rack-Cache: invalidate, pass
00:44:26.717678 < X-Request-Id: 19ff002048e4e2d5e17a8203576a4194
00:44:26.717708 < X-Runtime: 0.008901
00:44:26.717739 < X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
00:44:26.717771 < transfer-encoding: chunked
00:44:26.717802 < Connection: keep-alive
00:44:26.717832 < 
00:44:26.717925 * Connection #0 to host APP.herokuapp.com left intact
00:44:26.717998 * Closing connection #0
```

You can see the 10 second delay between the initial timestamp and the connect() call.  I already tried to see if resolving the host was the issue by doing `host APP.herokuapp.com` in my shell, but that returns immediately.

**UPDATE 3/28 #4**

I've updated the above example to include the `-4` flag so that it forces using ipv4 and it returns immediately on my development machine:

```
date +"%T" && curl -4 -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"user":"payload"}' http://APP.herokuapp.com/users.json -v --trace-time -S
```

I tried disabling ipv6 on my machine using the steps at `http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/05/how-to-disable-ipv6-under-ubuntu.html`, but it's still not working.  Now the problem is that the requests I want to make are through Net::HTTP and HTTParty, so I'd like to fix the IPv6 issue system-wide, so this band-aid on the curl is not a solution.

Comment: I have an app on Heroku n it handles POSTs incredibly fast, so I'd imagine they are slowing down programmatic requests to the single dyno so you can't keep it loaded in memory by pinging it

Comment: There's no rate limiting on Heroku. Are you doing any kind of processing or database queries when handling the POST? You might want to add something like New Relic to figure out what is going on: https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic

Comment: Yes, the POST does a simple DB insert, but this happens in like 20ms on my PC, so I can't imagine it takes much longer on the Heroku server.  I just checked the heroku logs to confirm this - it returns very quickly  I did 1400 of these POSTS today and all of them took 10 seconds exactly - see edited post above for some of the log entries.

Comment: Pretty strange results.  Have you tried using New Relic to see what parts of the request are taking so long?

Comment: Just added New Relic and the average response times are around 100ms with almost all of the time due to Request Queueing - very little on ruby or DB.  Hmmmm.  Can we trust that New Relic is reporting this correctly after everything that just went down?  I guess there could also be something happening in that `Net::HTTP::Post` call, but it's strange that it returns immediately when I'm aimed at localhost and takes exactly 10 seconds when I aim at Heroku.

Comment: The "controversy" over request queuing on Heroku was, as far as I am concerned, due to misconfiguration on the part of the app author (and admittedly inconsistent Heroku documentation due to some pages being left over from pre-Cedar stacks).  Either way, it seems strange you would be experiencing consistently 10-second delays like that.  I would expect those kinds of delays on a free dyno if the requests were spaced hours apart, because free dynos are spun down for inactivity, but if they're close together I'm not sure.

Comment: Try switching to unicorn to serve your app (this is recommended whether you're having trouble or not).  If that doesn't work, try upgrading to the two-dyno system temporarily and see if that's different (you pay by the second, so the test shouldn't be too difficult to run without paying much or any money).  Either way, the results from New Relic simply suggest the request is being delayed before it reaches your app's program code, so that narrows the problem down.

Comment: I just switched to a 2 dyno system and I'm seeing the same results.  Will try your unicorn suggestion this afternoon.

Comment: Adding update above - just tried the same post with curl and it also took 10 seconds.

Comment: Just switched to unicorn on my Heroku app and still getting the 10 second delay with both Ruby Net::HTTP::Post and using curl from the shell.  Switching to localhost, the post comes back immediately.  This is strange.

Comment: I agree, that really is strange.  I would probably contact Heroku support at this point and point them at this post and comment thread; there is one more thing you might try to narrow it down, which is using `heroku run` to open a shell and then using curl from that shell on localhost.  If it takes 10 seconds, then the problem is at your dyno; if it doesn't, then the problem is at Heroku's routing layer.

Answer (score 0):

What do the logs on Heroku indicate for the time used to process your requests? The logs are accurate with all the apps I've run on Heroku (both dev and production) with respect to time used. Are the heroku logs showing 10 seconds used for each request or is that some timing mechanism on the client side?

I would try removing some part of the code path temporarily to see if you can narrow down what might be taking up the time. For example, you might skip trying to render any complex views but instead render a 200 right from the controller. Next, maybe try commenting out the controller code. Keep taking out various parts until you find what is consuming the time.

Comment: The 10 seconds I'm seeing are in logs in my client-side rake task that is sending POSTs to my heroku site (and also see the same 10 second consistent delays doing a POST with curl and through ruby's Net::HTTP).  Both New Relic and the heroku logs are showing very quick response times on my Heroku instance.  I'm going to talk to heroku support.

Comment: it sounds like your rake task has a code path which is using up that time, not something related to your service code. I'd look more in-depth to what your rake task is doing. Not much help, I know. Good luck.

Comment: It's not the rake task as both curl requests and Net::HTTP requests are behaving the same way as when I have the calls in a rake task.